# Is there a way to automatically "lift" function-like macros to real inline functions?

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor, inline-functions

I'm assigned to review and renew an old private library, which contains tons of `do { .. } while(0)` macros.

After some investigations, I decided to replace them with static inline functions. After some manual works, I soon found this process kind of tedious and no-brain, which made me wonder if there is a way to do the "lifting" automatically.

I did not find an existing solution. However, there is a project on the reverse direction: https://github.com/akiradeveloper/macro-of-inline.

I was wondering if there is already an existing solution which I'm not aware of, or is it possible to build such a "lifting" tool.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries, or other off-site resources are off-topic. Regarding*is it possible*, the answer is yes. It is possible for you to write such a tool yourself.

Comment: Every such function should not necessarily be inlined even if marked with `inline`. That's a weakness with function-like macros, they don't give the compiler the same flexibility to prevent needless code repetition in the executable. Forcing everything to get inlined or writing everything as function-like macros might lead to very big executables.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently this answer need to be updated for certain missing details that's not obvious at the moment.

I think this can be done by replacing the following in the code editor:

- `#define` -> `static inline return_type_t`
- `do` -> *delete this*
- `while(0)` -> *delete this*

Also, all macro parameters need to have types added to them.

Comment: And therein lies the hard part — what are the appropriate types for the arguments?  And when the macro calculates a value, how is that returned?  Typically, it will be assigned to a macro parameter, unless the macro assumes that some specific variable is available for use.  For many real-world macros that I encounter, there would need to several names for several different types — `max` being a classic example of this problem.  It is not easy to do the mapping automatically.